# Bing Maps (Silverlight) maps - specifying canvas to be at foreground through XAML

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, google-maps, bing-maps

Below is the XAML code i have for a Bing Maps Silverlight weather related implementation.

Here is what i am trying to do:

1. Have a bing maps with several (over 100) pushpins- on mouseover - show a contentpopup (canvas=myPopup) below. Simple enough.
2. Everything works fine - however, when mypopup displays on mouseover, it is not on the foreground (the other pins appear on top of the contentpopup) - hence making it not very readable.

Question:

How do i specifiy the myPopup canvas specified in XAML below to always appear in the foreground, i.e. top most of the Bing Maps silverlight control when a user views it on mouseover.

Thanks!

---

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <m:Map x:Name="GlobalMap" Mode="Road"  Center="15,7" ZoomLevel="2" CredentialsProvider="{StaticResource MyCredentials}" Margin="-70,-40,-100,-72">

        <m:MapLayer x:Name="myLayer">
            <Canvas x:Name="myPopup" Visibility="Collapsed" Opacity="1">
                <Rectangle x:Name="myPopupRectangle" Fill="White" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Height="100" 
                           Width="100" RadiusX="15" RadiusY="15"/>
                <StackPanel Canvas.Left="8" Canvas.Top="8">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="myPopupTexts" FontSize="5" Width="100">
                    </TextBlock>

                </StackPanel>
            </Canvas>
        </m:MapLayer>
    </m:Map>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `Canvas.ZIndex` to the **MapLayer** element, give it a large value like 200 or add your push pins to another MapLayer (rather than adding the pins directly to the map) that appears ahead of this popup layer in document order.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to this, but took a different approach.  What I did was create a custom pushpin template and create a PopUp within the template.

When the user hovers over the pushpin, the popup is displayed. **Using the PopUp will solve your problem, since the control will automatically position it on top of everything**.  Try wrapping the Canvas in a PopPup and see if that works.

hth

Comment: Thanks for your esponse. The custom pushpin popup cannot handle html tags (Which i am displaying as part of the Canvas).. so that option wont work for my needs. I'm hoping there is a property on the canvas that will always display in the forefront/foreground (on top of everything else).