# Bing Maps for WPF , ZIndex of MapLayers/Pushpins?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, z-index, bing-maps

Just a preface that I realize that I am executing my solution in a non-WPF friendly way. in a perfect world I would be using MapItemsControl.

Ok, so I am using Bing Maps control for WPF. Here is my Bing maps XAML

```
<m:Map CredentialsProvider="12345" 
           x:Name="myMap" UseInertia="True" Loaded="Map_Loaded"
           Width="1920" Height="990" Canvas.Top="110" ZoomLevel="5" Center="39.8282,-98.5795">
    <m:MapLayer x:Name="MyPushPinLayer">                
        <Canvas x:Name="ContentPopup" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="250">
            <Border Background="White" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" Width="250" Padding="5">
                <StackPanel Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="10">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ContentPopupText" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#CF0000" Width="240" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                        </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ContentAddress" FontSize="13" Foreground="Black" Width="240"  TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ContentQuestions" FontSize="13" Foreground="Black" Width="240" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Canvas>
    </m:MapLayer>
</m:Map>
```

Basically, this draws a map and i have a maplayer that will hold the tool tip info when clicked. In my code behind I am pulling data from a service and adding pushpins procedurally to the map like so:

```
Pushpin pin = new Pushpin();
pin.Location = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(location.latitude, location.longitude);
pin.Content = location.name;
pin.Template = LGPushPinTemplate;

pin.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(pin_MouseDown);
myMap.Children.Add(pin);
```

Pretty straightforward. However, because I am defining the popup layer in the XAML and the children after the map is loaded, the pushpins are appearing last in the child structure of the map and therefore the modal infobox appears underneath any pushpins. Is there a way to rearrange the z-order of these items without adding/removing everything from the child collection of the map?|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This problem is solvable.** I found a few possible solutions while searching around. See below. Hopefully, you will find something that works with your code/situation.

1. Could you dynamically create the popup layer at the end? Similar to how you are generating the push pins.
2. Set the popups `Canvas.ZIndex` to a large number. Here are some more solutions with ZIndex: [silverlight control: how to manage the ZIndex?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vemapcontroldev/thread/477b6654-b851-4a68-bb5d-492c8cad3028)

   > The zindex is an attached property of the parent canvas.
   >
   > For example we created an "enhancedMapLayer" for the Bing Maps
   >   Silverlight control in http://deepearth.codeplex.com and added the
   >   zindex as a property like so:
   >
   > ```
   > public int ZIndex
   > {
   >     get { return zIndex; }
   >     set
   >     {
   >         zIndex = value;
   >         if (Parent != null)
   >         {
   >             SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, zIndex);
   >         }
   >      }
   >  }
   > ```
   >
   > The in our infogeometry class (provides labels, balloons for all the
   >   OGC geometry type, point, linestring, polygon, multipolygon etc) when
   >   we launch the balloon we do this:
   >
   > ```
   >    var layer = (EnhancedMapLayer) Parent;
   >    if (layer != null)
   >    {
   >        //set to top z-order
   >        prevZIndex = layer.ZIndex;
   >        layer.ZIndex = 1000;
   >        SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, 1000);
   >        applyTranslations();
   >        balloonShowStoryboard.Begin();
   >        balloonContainer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
   >        OnBalloon(new BalloonEventArgs { LayerID = layer.ID, ItemID = ItemID });
   >    }
   > ```
   >
   > By storing the layer's previous `ZIndex` we can restore it to the correct
   >   order on hiding the balloon.
   >
   > In order to communicate between layers we used the command pattern for
   >   Silverlight so we simply call:
   >
   > `Commands.ClosePopupCommand.Execute();`
   >
   > To close all other balloon then subscribe to that event:
   >   `Commands.ClosePopupCommand.Executed += ClosePopupCommand_Executed;`
3. [This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10418942/1085891) provides a good approach including mention of [Microsoft's Interactive Map SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/silverlight/#MapControlInteractiveSdk.Tutorials.UIElements.TutorialPositionLocation). Basically, try separating the layers.

   ```
       <m:Map CredentialsProvider="Your Key">
           <m:MapLayer>
               <m:MapItemsControl x:Name="ListOfItems"
                           ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LogoTemplate}"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding MyLocalizedEntities}">
               </m:MapItemsControl>
           </m:MapLayer>
           <m:MapLayer>
               <!-- You can have content in multiple layers: Latter layers are infront of former ones. -->
           </m:MapLayer>
       </m:Map>
   ```
4. Other similar stackoverflow questions that might help.

   - [ZIndex of pushpins in WP7 bing map control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148585/zindex-of-pushpins-in-wp7-bing-map-control)
   - [Bing Maps (Silverlight) maps - specifying canvas to be at foreground through XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299426/bing-maps-silverlight-maps-specifying-canvas-to-be-at-foreground-through-xam)

Comment: The solution was found in this question which you linked to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299426/bing-maps-silverlight-maps-specifying-canvas-to-be-at-foreground-through-xam

Basically I added the pins in the codebehind to a maplayer and not directly to the map. And because the MapLayers are all attached in correct order via XAML it seems to work. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help. Still plan on awarding the bounty?

Comment: Yes. It says I can award the bounty in 4 hours? I have never asked a bounty before so this is new to me. I think it wants me to leave the bounty for at least 24 hrs before I award it.